# Changing URL of XmlHttpRequest results in cookies not being sent

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've got an internal web server that presents an interface to let me view and change some data on that server.  When I am in one location I can access the server directly, but from another location I have to create an ssh tunnel to the server.  As a result, the URL I put in my browser changes depending on my location: for instance, `http://myserver/blah` versus `http://localhost:8000/blah`.  It's the same server, just a different host name.

This is inconvenient because occasionally I will forget to save my changes in one location and when I go to the other location the server is suddenly not found.  It's also inconvenient because I keep having to reload the page. I would like to just load the page once and have it work in either place.   So, I thought I would add some code in my XmlHttpRequest handling to detect if the server is not found and re-issue the request using the alternate server address.  The problem is, when this happens I find that my cookies are not sent to the server.

I've got cookies for both `localhost` and `myserver`.  They are the really the same set of values because it's really the same server, but they are duplicated obviously because the server is accessed from two different host names.  If I manually change the host name of the server I have no problem, but obviously this is what I am trying to avoid having to do.

I suspect that perhaps there is some security issue, but after re-reading how cookies work I can't figure out specifically might be tripping this behavior, or how to fix it.

By the way, the problem is NOT that I am trying to do a cross-site request.  I explicitly allow this on the server side by returning the field "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" and I have had no problem with this part of the request.   With firebug I can see the problem is that when the request is re-issued to the new host name, no cookies are sent, even though cookies exist for that host name.